# Running PHP inside PNG

Tags: php, image, header, png, gd

I just wondered.. 
I've seen that some pictures can have "arguments" in an url like this:

```
http://example.com/images/picture.png?width=120
```

But when I google it, I get instructions where the result would be like this:

```
http://example.com/images/picture.php?width=120
(with header("Content-type: image/png") and so on)
```

(How) can i make a piece of php-code run in a "picture"?

Comment: That would involve URL rewriting, and thus it is webserver-specific.

Comment: The first one is based on `mod_rewrite` (if it is PHP) and the second one is PHP running GD lib (or similar) to resize the picture on output.

Comment: @MarekSebera You don't need `mod_rewrite`.

Comment: @KingCrunch but it is a usual way to do url rewrite, so I mentioned it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In fact *nobody* cares about the file extension, it's just a hint usually for desktop applications only on how to handle the file, when you just double click it. However, behind the URL is a normal script of whatever language, that returns the header `Content-Type: image/png` alongside with an image as binary.

For example in PHP

```
// do something
header('Content-Type: image/png');
readfile('/local/path/to/a/prepared/image.png');
```

Comment: In fact, when you're implementing a website for a client, _somebody_ (namely: the client) might very much care about meaningless details like the apparent extension in the URL, and it might be unfeasible to persuade them otherwise.

Comment: @lanzz "nobody" in the meaning of "something technical" ;) As mentioned: They are always only a part of the filename, nothing more. When the client wants it, It's ok (would be more effort to remove it from physical files than just keep it anyway ;)). A webserver, or proxy may use it too, for example to set a default cache time or something like that. There are definitely use-cases, but `*.png` doesn't say "It is a physical image file", only "You can treat it as an image".

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. However, you can configure your web server to retrieve url B (which is a PHP script) when someone requests url A (which might be anything, including something that looks like it points to a picture). In fact that's the crucial point here: URLs only mean what the entity responsible for satisfying the requests wants them to mean.

There's official documentation on how to do url rewriting for all popular web servers (e.g. [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/)).

Comment: -1 You can. If you setup the server to parse .png files as .php.

Comment: @PeeHaa: That doesn't make PHP code run "in a picture", just as renaming .php to .mp3 doesn't make PHP code run in a sound. At least that's how I see it.

Comment: In a "picture" as OP states? Maybe. Depends on OP's definition of a picture. As I read it "picture" with quotes it isn't really a picture.

Answer (score 0):

look this: http://www.les-stooges.org/pascal/webdesign/vignettes/index.php?la=en
that's exactly what you ask ;)

Add:

```
<img src='vignette.php?f=example1.jpg'>
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, url rewriting takes charge of converting url a to url b allowing a user to use .png .jpg .whatever and convert it to .php

The php file itself outputs the raw image data and sets its header so the browser knows how to handle the returned data.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is make the *web server* execute a script in response to this URL.

URLs are not files, a URL is simply a *request* that a web server can do anything with and spit out a *response* in return. You can configure your web server to execute any file ending in .png as a PHP file, or you can use URL rewrite rules to tell the server that the URL should be handled by a regular .php file instead of serving a file in some directory.

Web servers are a black box. They take a *request* from the client and respond with some data in return. Whatever happens in-between is totally up to the server, just because the request contains the string ".png" doesn't mean the server *has* to serve a PNG image straight from the hard disk.

```
                    +-------------------+
---- request ---->  |     Web Server    |
                    |  Here be dragons! |
<--- response ----  |  Or PHP scripts.  |
                    +-------------------+
```